# How to arrange/subdivide code into clear sections?

Tags: language-agnostic, markup

I'd really like to do divide my code into sections and subsections using a tree and/or headings.

I'm currently working with php, and it would be so nice if I could make a comment flag heading of 22px saying **"Generator Section"** and then two subheadings in 20px saying **"MySQL Queries"** and **"Generate HTML Output"** each one followed by it's code.

Like so:

## Generator Section

### MySQL Queries

*code*

### Generate HTML Output

*code*

Only with indent.

Is this possible in any editor? It would seem odd if mankind is able to achieve so much but not something like this...

Answer (score 0):

A lot of IDEs allow some configuring of the display.  Point sizes are unusual, but you may be able to configure the colour of some types of comments.

Alternatively, I sometimes use a Comment Box to highlight a section heading:

```
//*****************
//* MySQL Queries *
//*****************
```

Comment: Any idea of an IDE name that would allow what I'm looking for? I'm using Geany btw.

Comment: You will have to read the manual, I'm afraid.  I don't use Geany.

Comment: Geany doesn't come with such features I'm afraid, only thing I can do is change comments to other colors and make them bold